# How we have multiple return statement in below code ? can any one explain how its working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am the guy who newly enter in angular.js. In javascript and jQuery we can return single statement.If we want to return more will fetch as array or object. But how its working here. Can any one please explain what is the concept here. Sorry for basic level question.

```
(function () {
    angular.module("app", ['ngRoute','app.controller']).config(["$routeProvider",
        function ($routeProvider) {
             var routes, setRoutes;
             return routes = ["test"],
            setRoutes = function (route) {
                var config, url;
                return url = "/" + route, 

                config = {
                    templateUrl: "views/" + route + ".html"                        
                },
                $routeProvider.when(url, config)
            }, 
            routes.forEach(function (route) {
                return setRoutes(route)
            }), 
            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                redirectTo: "/test"
            }).when("/404", {
                templateUrl: ""
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/testNone"
            })

        }
    ]).run( function() {

        });
}.call(this));
```

Comment: I do not know why anyone would use this code. It makes use of the comma operator, essentially only the last thing is returned but all are evaluated. Try with `function f(){ return 1,2,3; }` (hint: returns 3)

Comment: I think the purpose of this is to kill the readability because, you know, why not?

Comment: Oh, man, I rarely downvote, but if I could downvote this original code (as opposed to the question), I would. That `return` statement should not be allowed!

Comment: Yes nikos. i tried comma separator before i rise this question. I go the output what u explained.

Comment: @deitch.The code is working . that is my concern

Answer (score 1):

There is no "concept" in that return statement, it doesn't make sense at all!
JavaScript has no way to return multiple values (like you can do in Python thanks to tuples) unless to return an array or an object literal (but it's anyway a single value returned by the function). In that code all the statements are executed and only the latest one is returned. Try this snippet as example:

```js
function f (){
  return 1, 2, 3;
}

alert(f());
```

the alert will be 3!
But of course it has no sense. You should avoid such idiocies and blame the author of the code ;)